# How to pre-populate a caldera form?

Tags: caldera-forms

I'm using a caldera form to register beneficiaries (they become member throughout their organization) and I want to have the 'organization name' field pre-populated from the url. And I don't want to show the name of the organization on a public form with a select list.

I read on the documentation that it is possible with example.com/some-page?cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum} but where do I find the contact cheksum and how do I insert it in the form?

Any experience connected to this topic?

Comment: I guess this extension gives me half of the answer: https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-checksum-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the process is easy:

1. In the Caldera form > tab Builder, add an hidden field with the value {get:field_name} (replace field_name by the desired value)
2. In the Caldera form > tab Process, add a CiviCRM process and match the needed field with the one from Caldera with the magic field syntax, so here %field_name%. (In my case, 'employee of' matches with '%organization_name%')
3. create an url to the page with the form: [www.domain.com/form/](http://www.domain.com/form/) and add ?field_name=YOURVALUE so it shows up like [www.domain.com/form/?organization_name=YOURVALUE](http://www.domain.com/form/?organization_name=YOURVALUE). You can also add several variables using '&' between them.
4. Add the User registration Process with password creation
5. Send the email from inside CiviCRM using such a syntax: [https://domain.com/form/?organization_name={contact.organization_name}](https://domain.com/form/?organization_name=%7Bcontact.organization_name%7D)

When processed, the new user gets a CiviCRM membership as a relation to the organization and can access specified content of the WordPress site!

Source: [Caldera form documentation](https://calderaforms.com/doc/using-magic-tags-caldera-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

How to use tokens such as checksum is covered [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#checksum) and is how you would send out a checksum via a bulk mailing

The extension [Contact Checksum UI](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-checksum-ui) adds ability to create an email for a one-off email to a Contact via the Actions button on the contact record.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I guess my question wasn't precise enough. I need to register someone that is not yet in the database but his/her organization is already. Is this actually possible?

Comment: i don't follow. how are you telling the person which Organisation?

Comment: are you wanting to give someone you know at the Org a link they can give to others who you don't know to use?

Comment: yes exactly! i want to be able to a send a personalized link to my contact in the organization that he/she will send to his colleagues and they will register themselves with a relation to the organization. this means I have to create each time a new link with the variable but it's part of job. I'm thinking about the simplest way to do this.